# How to solve java.util.NoSuchElementException in this code?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name : ");
        String name=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter your age : ");
        int age=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("hello "+name+". you're "+age+" old.");
    }
}
```

Exception:
Enter your name : Exception in thread "main"

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found   at
> java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)     at
> Main6347b255eeb1595.main(Main6347b255eeb1595.java:8)

Comment: Try to use `if(sc.hasNextLine())` before actually trying to read the next line. JavaDoc on `hasNextLine()`: "This method may block while waiting for input.".

Answer (score 0):

At least something like this can be done:

```
String name = "";
if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    name = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Or even better you can use optionals not to have empty line.